# Stateless worker service and api service both referencing same project

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric solution that contains the following:

1. Worker service (.net framework 4.7)
2. Api Service (.net core 2.0 as VS 2017 does not provide a template for framework api services)
3. Infrastructure project (.net standard) referencing EntityFrameworkCore

Both services reference infrastructure project.
This gives me issues as the framework service will not load EntityFrameworkCore reference due to it being core.

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Can I force the core to load EF 6.2?

Can I force 4.7 to load EFCore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiy Framework Core is .NET Standard as well, it should load fine on .NET Framework 4.7.

You may need to add the EF Core NuGet packages to the worker service if it doesn't yet use the transitive NuGet package reference style.

Comment: That seems to have fixed my issue, i'm getting EF errors now :)